# Changing collation for all mysql session

Tags: mysql, collation

I have multilingual CRM system that has `uft_general_ci` collation. For some clients, I have to use different collation.

Is there a way to change collation for all mysql session? (Altering mysql tables isn't good for me).

`"SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'"`

That query doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes (in general) are only usable with the collation that they are built with.

In MySQL collations are defined per field, so the best I can think of is to have separate fields (with their own indexes) for every collation that will be used.

You can auto fill them from a 'master' field with some BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers, but the choice of which field to select/search will have to be made by the application.